# How migrate an actuator that extends AbstractMvcEndpoint to Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In Spring Boot 1.5.x, I created an actuator endpoint by extending `AbstractMvcEndpoint`. But this class no longer exists in Spring Boot 2.x.

How would I upgrade the following class?

```
@Configuration
@ManagementContextConfiguration
public class MyManagementController extends AbstractMvcEndpoint
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyManagementController.class );

    public MyManagementController()
    {
        super( "/mypath, false, true );
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void completeSetup()
    {
        setEnabled( true );
    }

    @GetMapping(
        value = "/" + PATH_PIECE_MANAGERS,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use annotation `@RestControllerEndpoint` with spring-boot 2.x, here you can have your own request mapping along with HttpMethods. Here is a sample:

```
    @Component
    @RestControllerEndpoint(id = "remote")
    public class CustomActuator {
        @RequestMapping(value = {"/{actuatorInput}"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> feature(@PathVariable("actuatorInput") String actuatorInput) {
            System.out.println("actuatorInput : " + actuatorInput);
            Map<String, Object> details = new HashMap<>();
            details.put("input", actuatorInput);
            return details;
        }
    }
```

Or, you can use `@Endpoint(id = "endpoint")` with which you can have `@ReadOperation` and `@WriteOperation` for GET and POST operations.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "custom-health")
public class CustomHealthEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public String customEndPointByName(@Selector String name) {
        return "custom-end-point : " + name;
    }
    @WriteOperation
    public void writeOperation(@Selector String name) {
        System.out.println("Write Operation! :: " + name);
    }
    @DeleteOperation
    public void deleteOperation(@Selector String name){
        System.out.println("Delete Operation! :: " + name);
    }
}
```

Refer: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator-custom-endpoint/

Comment: `@Endpoint` is the way we migrated all of ours. Very simple to do.

Comment: I believe Endpoint is a preferred way. We used Endpoint in most, but RestControllerEndpoint for a few as it seems to provide more flexibility.